# How to subscribe to a gerrit project?

Tags: gerrit

How do I subscribe to a gerrit project, so that I will be notified, whenever a new change is uploaded.

Thanks, 
Ravi

Answer (score 6):

*Settings*->*Watched Projects*->*Browse*, select appropriate project, enter branch name if required, hit *Watch*. Done.

[image]

Comment: related question, Can we watch a specific directory in a project? I have tried adding in "Only if" row above , but unable to add. Can you help?

Comment: @kumar No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the documentation. See documentation here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/watched_projects

Answer (score 0):

To answer [Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124330/kumar)'s question (in a comment) -

You can watch a specific folder/file via the **[reviewers](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/reviewers/)** plugin.

**Some examples**

```
[filter "*"]
  reviewer = john.doe@example.com

[filter "branch:main file:^lib/.*"]
  reviewer = jane.doe@example.com

[filter "branch:stable-2.10"]
  reviewer = QAGroup
```